# Should every app with GCM support have "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"

Tags: android, android-permissions

All the apps I've seen which have GCM support have

```
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
```

I would like to know the reason behind this.

**What happens if an app which supports GCM doesn't have this permission?**

Answer (score 1):

According to the Google documentation it is optional:

> The android.permission.WAKE_LOCK permission so the application can keep the processor from sleeping when a message is received. Optional—use only if the app wants to keep the device from sleeping.

Source: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Comment: What happens if an app which supports GCM doesn't have this permission?

Comment: @gameover Assuming the Google documentation is up to date. It shouldn't matter.

Comment: It matters. when your application needs to do some work from background. It has no relation with GCM. Read some articles about why we use WAKE_LOCK.

Comment: @PankajKumar But the question specifically asks about the correlation between GCM and the WAKE_LOCK and what happens if an app which supports GCM doesn't have it. If it doesn't need it, it doesn't matter. If the app needs it, it does of course matter.